# React: What means "Redirect to { pathname: '/', state: { from: props.location }

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to React and I don't understand what the meaning of:

```
<Redirect to={{ pathname: '/', state: { from: props.location } }} />}
```

What does the state is doing here, and particularly what means "from: props.location" ?

**EXAMPLE**

```
 const PrivateRoute = ({component: Component, ...rest}) => {
    return (
       <Route
           {...rest}
            render={(props) => getToken() ? <Component {...props} /> : <Redirect to={{ pathname: '/signin', state: { from: props.location } }} />}
       />
    );
};
```

and what the difference between:

```
 <Redirect to="/" />
```

AND

```
  <Redirect to={{ pathname: '/'}}
```

Is it just a more concise syntax ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What does the state is doing here, and particularly what means "from: props.location" ?

The react-router library handles updating the page when the url changes. The url is the pathname part. In addition, they let you have a router state, which is an object of custom data that you can use however you need to. It's not a part of the url, so there's no way to deep link into a page with state, but it can be useful when moving within pages in your app. This code apparently wants to remember the value that `props.location` had before the redirect, so the `{from: props.location}` is some custom data to do that.

> what the difference between [...] Is it just a more concise syntax ?

Yes, it's just a more concise version. Usually all you need is the pathname, so the redirect component is designed to assume that a string is meant to be the pathname.

Comment: Thank you! and if then I want to get the value in the "from",should I do: 
export function SignIn(props) {
  ....    props.from  <-- ??

Comment: I found the answer, should be sthg like props.location.state.from